# Rarely Occured Error: Binary XML file line #196: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, drawable

I have an issue its error: Binary XML file line #196:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

This error occurs sometimes and sometimes not for the same actions where I use animation-list. It causes a crash. After the crash, I reopen the app and do the same thing, but I don't have that type of error.

An error occurred approximately one time every 10 actions are the same. I can't get what is wrong and why it occurs rarely and not all time.

Every attempt is after creating activity.

My java code:

```
package com.edulab.akiciokuma;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

public class AnimationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer player;
private AnimationDrawable running;
private ImageView anime;
private String  animwhich, strategy, condition;
private int level;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = 
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private String[] animalIntro = {"tosbaameeting", "zipzipintro", 
"foxintro", "atintro", "deveintro", "cheetahintro"};
private String[] animalModel = {"tosbaamodel", "zipzipmodel", 
"foxmodel", "atmodel", "devemodel", "cheetahmodel"};
private String[] animalModel2 = {"tosbaamodel2", "zipzipmodel2", 
"foxmodel2", "atmodel2", "devemodel2", "cheetahmodel2"};
private String[] animalReread = {"tosbaareread", "zipzipreread", 
"foxreread", "atreread", "devereread", "cheetahreread"};
private String[] animalReread2 = {"tosbaareread2", "zipzipreread2", 
"foxreread2", "atreread2", "devereread2", "cheetahreread2"};
private String[] animalReread3 = {"tosbaareread3", "zipzipreread3", 
"foxreread3", "atreread3", "devereread3", "cheetahreread3"};
private String[] animalshutup = {"tosbaailk6", "zipzipgozuacik2", 
"foxacik5", "atacik6", "deveacik4", "cheetahacik5"};
private boolean intro = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);
    initializeVariables();  //initializing variables
    if(animwhich.equals("intro")){
        intro = true;
        setvideo(animalIntro[(int) Math.floor(level/12.1)]);
    }
    else{
        if(animwhich.equals("model")) {
            if(strategy.equals("x"))
                setvideo(animalModel2[(int) Math.floor(level/12.1)]);
            else
                setvideo(animalModel[(int) Math.floor(level/12.1)]);
        }else {
            if (animwhich.equals("reread")) {
                switch (Integer.parseInt(condition)){
                    case 2:
                        setvideo(animalReread2[(int) 
  Math.floor(level/12.1)]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        setvideo(animalReread3[(int) 
 Math.floor(level/12.1)]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        setvideo(animalReread[(int) 
Math.floor(level/12.1)]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeVariables() {
    animwhich = configureText("animwhich", "model");
    strategy = configureText("strategy", "y");
    condition= configureText("condition", "1");
    level = configureNumber("level");
    anime =  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

private void setvideo(final String file) {
    anime.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().
            getIdentifier("drawable/" + file, null, 
 getPackageName())));
    running = (AnimationDrawable) anime.getDrawable();
    running.start();
    if (player == null) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
 getResources().getIdentifier(file, "raw", getPackageName()));
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new 
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlayer();
            }
        });
    }
    if (player != null) {
        player.start();
    }
}

private void stopPlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
        running.stop();
        final Intent getData = getIntent();
        
 anime.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().
                getIdentifier("drawable/" + animalshutup[(int) 
Math.floor(level/12.1)], null, getPackageName())));
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Intent intent;
                if (animwhich.equals("reread")) {
                    intent = new Intent(AnimationActivity.this, 
Reread1Activity.class);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopPlayer();
}

private int configureNumber(String tag){
    Intent getData = getIntent();
    int value;
    if(getData.getStringExtra(tag)==null)
        value=1;
    else
    if(getData.getStringExtra(tag).matches("-?([1- 
    9]\\d*)")&&Integer.parseInt(getData.getStringExtra(tag))>0)
        value= Integer.parseInt(getData.getStringExtra(tag));
    else
        value=1;
    return value;
}

private String configureText(String tag, String deflt){
    Intent getData = getIntent();
    String value;
    if(getData.getStringExtra(tag)==null)
        value=deflt;
    else
    if(getData.getStringExtra(tag).isEmpty())
        value=deflt;
    else
        value= getData.getStringExtra(tag);
    return value;
}
}
```

My screen xml code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/arkaplansabit"
    android:id="@+id/backgr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

My animation list xml code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="1600"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="300"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali1"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali2"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali3"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali4"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali5"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali6"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="300"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="400"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali1"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali2"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali3"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali4"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali5"
    android:duration="50"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali6"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="1100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali1"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali2"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali4"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali5"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali6"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="800"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="500"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali1"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali2"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali3"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali4"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali5"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozukapali6"
    android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="400"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik3"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik4"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik5"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik6"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/zipzipgozuacik2"
    android:duration="20000"/>
```

Please help me with this issue.

THANK YOU

Comment: please share the XML code.

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I shared the XML code @MuntasirAonik

Comment: I also shared other codes. Please help